# Unix Shell script code meaning for beginner

Tags: shell, unix

I am a novice learner of Unix and shell scripting.
Can anyone explain the meaning of this line and how it works:

```
Record_count=$(wc -l ${table_dir} "/" $table_file_name | cut -d' ' f1)
```

I am not sure of what "/" does here.

Comment: this is filepath separator

Comment: I believe some characters got lost while writing the command in this question. In particular f1 looks odd. Please make sure the question contains the exact command.

Comment: As it is written, this command does not do anything useful. Either you made a mistake when doing the copy and paste, or the author didn't know what he was doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step.

**First step**. This `wc -l ${table_dir} "/" $table_file_name` doesn't work as it's written but I understand it means **return the number of lines (`wc -l`) of the file `${table_dir}/${table_file_name}`**. It returns something that looks like this (imagining that `your_table_file_name.txt` has 5 lines):

```
$ wc -l wc -l "${table_dir}/${table_file_name}"
5 your_table_dir/your_table_file_name.txt
```

**Second step**. I think this `cut -d' ' f1` has a typo and is actually `cut -d ' ' -f1`. What this does is splitting a line by the space character (`cut -d ' '`) and only returns the first item of the sequence (`-f1`).

So, when you apply it to your line `5 your_table_dir/your_table_file_name.txt`, it returns `5`.

**Third step**. So what `wc -l "${table_dir}/${table_file_name}" | cut -d ' ' -f1` does is returning the number of lines that `${table_dir}/${table_file_name}` has.

**Final step**. In shell script, `foo=$(some_command)` means: assign to the variable called `foo`, the result of the command `some_command`.

So, what your whole line `Record_count=$(wc -l "${table_dir}/${table_file_name}" | cut -d ' ' -f1)` does is assigning to the variable `Record_count`, the count of the lines of the file `${table_dir}/${table_file_name}`.